# Why does this alert get completely ignored by the program?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm standing in front of a little problem: I wanted to try ts with Ionic, and start with a little alert after a button click. So I wrote a function for an alert, but that didn't work. O.K. I thought, let's try a piece of code of the internet. Doesn't work either. The thing is, the function on it's own works, I mean, it does something (when there is a console.log inside). The whole this.alertCtrl.create() doesn't do anything. The console.log does what it should be doing, writing "Test1" into the console, but the rest gets ignored. Maybe someone of you knows this problem or the solution of it.

This is the code of my ts-file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController) {}

async presentAlertConfirm() {
  const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
  header: 'Confirm!',
  message: 'Message <strong>text</strong>!!!',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
      cssClass: 'secondary',
      handler: (blah) => {
        console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
      }
    }, {
      text: 'Okay',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Confirm Okay');
      }
    }
  ]
});
console.log("Test");
alert.present();
}

}
```

This is the html file:

```
<ion-app>
   <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>

<ion-content >
   <div>
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      <ion-button (click)="presentAlertConfirm()">
         Test1
      </ion-button>
   </div>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Could you show the HTML file?

Comment: The HTML file is now added :)

Comment: Your code worked for me...https://imgur.com/a/RYi82LH

 Could you try changing the Single Quotes by double quotes? All your single quotes in your typescript file

Comment: So you see the alert? Because even with all the Single Quotes changed to Double Quotes it won't work for me. Might there be something i have forgotten to do?

Comment: When you open the Inspect with Chrome, do you see anything, any warning, or mistake, or error? Even yellow warning? Also, try creating a new component, and implement this in this new component